# How to calculate previous month from \today using datetime2?

Tags: datetime2

Is is possible to use `datetime2` to calculate the previous month from `\today`?
(Alternatively another package).

I've found some solutions that use negative deduction of days, but that would cause problems around the end of the month.

Example: `\today` = 12-JUL-2017

Wanted output: "Today is 12-JUL-2017. Last month was June."

Comment: you can try `\DTMenglishmonthname{\numexpr\month-1\relax}`

Answer (score 3):

You can save the current date using `\DTMsavenow` and then use `\DTMfetchmonth` and `DTMmonthname` or its equivalents to calculate the previous (or next) month.  I've added both a `\lastmonth` and `\nextmonth` version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand\lastmonth[1]{\ifthenelse{\DTMfetchmonth{#1}=1}
    {\DTMmonthname{12}}{\DTMmonthname{\numexpr\DTMfetchmonth{#1}-1\relax}}}
\newcommand\nextmonth[1]{\ifthenelse{\DTMfetchmonth{#1}=12
    {\DTMmonthname{1}}{\DTMmonthname{\numexpr\DTMfetchmonth{#1}+1\relax}}}
\begin{document}
\DTMsavenow{today}
\DTMsavedate{jan20}{2017-01-20}
Today is \today.
Last month was \lastmonth{today}.

Today is \DTMusedate{jan20}.
Last month was \lastmonth{jan20}.

Next month is \nextmonth{jan20}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: What happens if this month is January?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot :) Oops.  I'll fix soon.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this without any packages. You can define your own `\lastmonth` macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% \setdate{<day>}{<month>}{<year>}
\newcommand{\setdate}[3]{\day=#1\month=#2\year=#3\relax}%
\newcommand{\lastmonth}{%
  \ifcase\month\or%  0
    December\or   %  1
    January\or    %  2
    February\or   %  3
    March\or      %  4
    April\or      %  5
    May\or        %  6
    June\or       %  7
    July\or       %  8
    August\or     %  9
    September\or  % 10
    October\or    % 11
    November\fi   % 12
}

\begin{document}

Today is \today.
Last month was \lastmonth.

\setdate{20}{1}{2017}%
Today is \today.
Last month was \lastmonth.

\end{document}
```