# Define a `\DTMifdate` conditional using the `datetime2` package and `\today`

Tags: conditionals, date, datetime2

I got a question regarding the usage of the `datetime2` package. I want to set some due date and to define a certain date such as `\paperdate` which is either `\today` when it's before the due date or the due date itself. I tried this based on an example from the package's documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[useregional, calc]{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\DTMsavedate{duedate}{2023-04-30}
\DTMifdate
{\today}
{at most=
\DTMfetchyear{duedate}-\DTMfetchmonth{duedate}-\DTMfetchday{duedate}}
{\newcommand\paperdate{\today}}{\newcommand\paperdate{\DTMusedate{duedate}}}

\end{document}
```

However, this code gives me the following error:
`` Package datetime2-calc Error: Unknown date `2023-04-23'. ``

Would anyone know a workaround? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself! Based on the discussion [How to calculate previous month from \today using datetime2?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380370/how-to-calculate-previous-month-from-today-using-datetime2) :

```
\usepackage[useregional, calc]{datetime2}

\begin{document}
\DTMsavenow{today}

\DTMsavedate{duedate}{2023-04-30}
\DTMifdate
{today}
{at most=
\DTMfetchyear{duedate}-\DTMfetchmonth{duedate}-\DTMfetchday{duedate}}
{\newcommand\paperdate{\today}}{\newcommand\paperdate{\DTMusedate{duedate}}}

\end{document}
```